# best way to rotate a sphere on a follow path

Tags: bezier-curves

i need the best way to precisely have a ball rotate on a nurbs path.
in the sample provided, i have the ball enter the scene and bounce, then go to the nurbs path (circle) and rotate for several rotation.
i tried adding a value on the rotation but the ball deforms into an egg shape.

is there someone who can help with this issue.

[image]

new file with deformed ball

[image]

Comment: there is no sample ....

Comment: trying to add sample, didn't work

Comment: It deosn't seem to deform like an egg in my case

Comment: i removed the rotation which allowed for the ball to return to normal size. If you try adding rotation to it, you will be able to see it deformed. i will add new blend file with deformation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the scale of your curve (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>), it deforms your ball when the ball rotates